# Как подсчитать сколько элементов (цифр) содержит переменная?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть переменная (`id_code = 56033343211`). Нужно сделать проверку, чтобы эта переменная всегда содержала `11` цифр

Comment: Зачем такие требования к переменной?

Comment: нужно чтобы ID состоял ровно из 11 цифр

Comment: Проверьте регуляркой, например: `^[0-9]{11}$`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Число находится в диапазоне `10 000 000 000..99 999 999 999`, если

```
 if (math.floor(math.log10(id_code)) == 10):
```

собственно, если пределы меняться не будет, можно просто

```
id_code = 56033343211
if (10000000000 <= id_code <= 99999999999):
    print('ok')
```

Comment: @MaxU Да, конечно

Comment: А как сделать чтобы можно было работать конкретно с первым или например с 2 и 3 числом?

Comment: Уточните, какое число имеется в виду?

Comment: например переменная id_code = 49808270244 (просто задание связанно с id) первое число (тут это первая 4) означает пол человека. 2 и 3 цифры последние цифри года рождения (эта девушка родилась в 1998 году). В общем нуджно вычленять цифры из кода (он может быть любым) и работать с ними.

Comment: id_code // 10000000 и оператор остатка %

Comment: Не понял как воспользоваться этой функцией

Comment: Сделать `(123456789 // 1000) % 100` и посмотреть

Answer (score 5):

```
assert len(str(id_code)) == 11, "[id_code] must contain exactly 11 digits"
```

NOTE: спасибо [@andreymal за подсказку](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/883576/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b4%d1%81%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%ba%d0%be-%d1%8d%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b2-%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%84%d1%80-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b6%d0%b8%d1%82-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%8f/883582?noredirect=1#comment1438707_883582):

при запуске Python с ключем `-O` (`remove assert and __debug__-dependent statements; add .opt-1 before .pyc extension; also PYTHONOPTIMIZE=x`) все вызовы `assert` будут проигнорированы.

Comment: Не стоит использовать ассерты для проверки (скорее всего) пользовательского ввода, так как они выпиливаются при включенных оптимизациях

Comment: @andreymal, можете ссылкой поделиться?

Comment: А зачем ссылкой, просто сравните `python -c 'assert False'` и `python -O -c 'assert False'`

Comment: @andreymal, спасибо, добавил "disclaimer"...

Answer (score 2):

```
if len(str(id_code)) != 11:
    raise ValueError('id_code содержит не 11 цифр!')
```